# Reflection coefficient derivation

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, intensity

from fresnel equations we have

$$r_{parallel}=\frac{n_1\cos\theta_i-n_2\cos\theta_r}{n_1\cos\theta_i+n_2\cos\theta_r}$$
$$r_{perpendicular}=\frac{n_2\cos\theta_i-n_1\cos\theta_r}{n_1\cos\theta_i+n_2\cos\theta_r}$$

reflection coefficient

$$R=r_{parallel}^2+r_{perpendicular}^2$$

am I right? I don't know, cannot find any information anywhere, just guessing.
Alright, therefore

$$R=2\cdot(\frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2+n_1})^2$$

but apparently the correct answer is

$$R=(\frac{n_2-n_1}{n_2+n_1})^2$$

I am not sure if that is correct answer either; it is written a lot all over the internet so I guess it is.

These two formulae are not the same, why the result I am getting is different? Need an explanation

Answer (score 1):

The power reflection factor is the average of

$R = \frac{1}{2}(r_{parallel}^2+ r_{perpendicular}^2)$

assuming

$\theta_i = \theta_r = 0$

Here it is also assumed that the  we have an equal amount of power in the s and p polarizations, as with "natural light".